# Сделать несворачивающееся окно (по Win+D) [not topmost]

Tags: winapi

Чисто WinAPI, язык не принципиален.

Ситуация такая: делаю окно, оно НЕ topmost, и оно должно оставаться на экране при нажатии <kbd>Win+M</kbd> и <kbd>Win+D</kbd>. Сейчас проверяю на Win7, но должно работать для любой.
<kbd>Win+M</kbd> вроде победил, а вот со вторым... Не могу понять, как вообще работает <kbd>Win+D</kbd> - окну не приходят сообщения, которые я логически ожидал при сворачивании/перемещении. А если как-то и получается заметить что свернули - не выходит запретить сворачивание.
Есть стандартная программа, которая имеет нужное поведение, но Spy++ вообще не может ничего в ней отловить, даже под админом (первый раз такое увидел).

Проблема, что при нажатии <kbd>Win+D</kbd> окна пропадают (сворачиваются). А не должны. Кто-то сталкивался с вопросом?

P.S. Возможно следует использовать какие-то новые интерфейсы оболочки Shell или DWM, но никак не найду какие. :(

Comment: Я новенький тут, не знал про тег "kbd", спасибо за правку!

Answer (score 4):

Надо изменить родительское окно, чтобы оно принадлежало Рабочему столу.
Также может понадобиться предварительно отключить его отображение на панели задач.

```
SetWindowLongPtr Me.hWnd, GWLP_HWNDPARENT, &H800F0
```

Где `&H800F0` - это хэндл рабочего стола.

Обращаю внимание, что вариант

```
SetParent Me.hWnd, &H800F0
```

не годится, поскольку он делает окно частью рабочего стола, и любые (даже неактивные) окна будут отображаться поверх него.

PS: Проверял на VB6, пришлось ещё в дизайнере формы выставить `ShowInTaskbar = False`, в противном случае окно сворачивается. Хендл рабочего стола узнал при помощи Spy++.

Comment: У большинства окон верхнего уровня нет ни "родителей" ни "владельцев". В том числе у того чужого окна, которое умеет не сворачиваться на Win+D.

Comment: @UI-Maker, создал форму на VB6. `GetWindowLongPtr(Me.hWnd, GWLP_HWNDPARENT)` возвращает не 0. Однако, попытка установить 0 к нужному эффекту не приводит. Есть подозрение, что надо найти какой-то конкретное окно и привязать к нему, но я не помню. Где-то точно про что-то такое читал. Хм.. А если к таскбару?

Comment: @UI-Maker, ответ обновлён. Надо было сделать ровно противоположное действие тому, которое я вспомнил изначально...

Comment: Спасибо, интересная информация!
Несколько глючит, но возможно получится допилить. Хотя смахивает на хак. :3
Только надо брать не константу, а примерно: GetWindow(FindWindow("Progman", NULL), GW_CHILD)
А то &H800F0 у меня не существует.

>> "GetWindowLongPtr возвращает не 0" <<

Большинство готовых библиотек-обёрток API делают невидимое окно "программа", а уже к нему дочерними создаются все формы. Программы на VCL и MFC так делают, видимо на VB тоже. Но по умолчанию у большинства окон стоит ноль.

Пробую как будет получаться с этим решением, но если у кого-то есть другие идеи - пишите.

Comment: ...блин, чего в каментах не работают переносы строк? Всё в одну строку сделало... :С

Comment: @UI-Maker, естественно, надо определять хендл программно. Я именно саму идею проверял. По поводу нуля - не уверен. У меня GetParent возвращал 0, но если лезть через GetWindowLongPtr GWLP_HWNDPARENT, то был не 0. А что именно у тебя глючит? PS: Да, переносы строк в комментариях не работают.