# Приложение PyQt5 сворачивается по нажатию Win+D

Tags: python, pyqt5

Хочу сделать виджет на PyQt5 для рабочего стола, в теории он не должен сворачиваться и должен находиться под всеми окнами. При выставлении следующих флагов и атрибутов все работает как надо, за исключением сворачивания на Win+D.

```
self.setWindowFlags(
    Qt.Window
    | Qt.WindowStaysOnBottomHint
    | Qt.CustomizeWindowHint
    | Qt.CoverWindow
    | Qt.FramelessWindowHint
)
self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground, True)
self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_ShowWithoutActivating, True)
```

Нашел вот [такое](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/453114/%D0%A1%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE-wind-not-topmost) решение, но как это реализовать на PyQt?

Comment: Так через winapi также меняй родителя. Айди окна получить не сложно

Comment: @eri, То есть в pyqt нету способа задать рабочий стол, как родителя виджета? Я пробовал через QApplication.desktop(), но судя по всему, это не то, что мне нужно

Comment: переопределите для окна обработчик closeEvent и игнорируйте в нем запрос на сворачивание

Comment: @sergey-tatarintsev, даже если и можно было так сделать, то скорее через hideEvent, но тут проблема в том, что Windows при нажатии win+d, судя по всему, отправляет какой то иной сигнал, отличный от обычного сворачивания, который не ловится даже обычным event'ом

Comment: Добавлю, что при нажатии на Win+D, и при попытке переключиться на любое приложение, мое приложение тоже разворачивается, и автоматически уходит на задний фон, как и должно быть